# Triangle centroid code

Tags: java, centroid

I am new to Java and I want to ask about code for calculating for the centroid of a triangle (by using POINT 2D class). Code that allows user to input x-coordinates, y-coordinates of the 3 vertices.

Comment: 1.) Calculate the 3 lines 2.) Solve a System of equations to find where they meet. This is more of a mathematical question than programming.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the centroid is as simple as finding the average of the coordinates. Below is some code that does just that.

```
final Point2D.Double p1 = ...;
final Point2D.Double p2 = ...;
final Point2D.Double p3 = ...;

final Point2D.Double centroid = new Point2D.Double((p1.getX() + p2.getX() + p3.getX()) / 3.0, (p1.getY() + p2.getY() + p3.getY()) / 3.0);
```

[Here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordcentroid.html) is a site that provides a neat little interactable that lets you see this in action.